# pjsip2 issue during build

Tags: android, macos, pjsip

I'm trying to use pjsip library for sip telephony in an android device for different architectures on a MAC.

I have downloaded 2.5.5 from http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/tags/2.5.5 which is build fine for armabi architectures with the corresponding libpjsua2.so.

I'm trying to build it for other architectures as well but with no much lack on it. I have followed the instructions from https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android but I have different errors.

For instance having `TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags` I was getting at the beginning:

/Users/*****/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/samples/hello-jni: No such file or directory.  Stop.
configure-android error: failed to run ndk-build, check ANDROID_NDK_ROOT env var

I downloaded the samples from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master) (as suggested in [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/index.html)) and now I get another error:

> Users/iu/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-local.mk:151:
>   *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop. ./configure-android: line 72: test: argument expected configure-android error: compiler not found,
>   please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc)

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: To make a useful question, better to focus on the one issue that you now have.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just mention the process I have followed on the hope it might help. To be honest I'm not sure what would be more useful as a question since I don't know how to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody has a similar issue. The way I solved it is by building it on a linux machine as described in

https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder

Answer (score 0):

For Android, I suggest, you build pjsip 2.6.
And yes, build it on Linux.
It has fixed many SIGSEG errors that occurred in 5.x versions.
Since we switched to 2.6 the stability of our app increased significantly.

It may happen, that another build issue arises with 2.6 that correlates with libYUV if you compile together with openSSL.
If you do not need video, disable it in the build (config_site.h).